# Transformations invariant wrt. $L_1$ norm.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

$A$ is a real matrix of size $n \times k$, where $k \leq n$. $A$ has independent columns.

Characterize the class of matrices $M \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ such that:

$\forall x \in \mathbb{R}^k.\; \| Ax \|_1 = \|AMx \|_1$

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?  What have you tried?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for taking the time to read my question. Unfortunately the only approach I could think of involves converting the norm into an inner product, but $L_1$ does not correspond to any inner product, so I am stuck. I'd be grateful for any hints or pointers to the literature.